# I cannot connect to a secure web site

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, https

I have an Intel Core 2 Duo 3.0 MHz 32-bit with 2 GB RAM. I have the latest version of Ubuntu 32-bit with the latest 32-bit versions of Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome.

If I go to a web site, like https://store.steampowered.com/ and then try to login, I get a message that `'Your connection is not secure'` (Firefox) or `'Your connection is not private'` (Chrome). The date and time on the computer are correct so that's not it.

Firefox will have this error code:

```
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

I don't think it is something specific to the web site, as it happens to all secure sites (like the same if I go to https://www.gog.com/ and try to log in) and I don't think it is the browser, as it happens with both Chrome and Firefox.

What else should I look at?

When I run:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.gog.com:443 -prexit </dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

I get [this output](//paste.ubuntu.com/21290497/). Money quote:

```
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/CN=*.gog.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Virginia/L=Reston/O=Digital Reflection/OU=Digital Reflection Certificate Authority/CN=Digital Reflection/emailAddress=support-team@digitalreflectionpanel.com
---
```

Comment: Google has discontinued Chrome for 32-bit Linux. You should really stop using it because it's old and insecure. Use Chromium or Firefox or Vivaldi instead.

Comment: Are you on a network with an HTTPS proxy server, e. g. from your university, employer or home internet access provider? Could you please install the `openssl` package, run `openssl s_client -connect www.gog.com:443 -prexit </dev/null 2>/dev/null >/tmp/www.gog.com.ssl-log`, upload the resulting `/tmp/www.gog.com.ssl-log` file (e. g. to http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post a link to it here?

Comment: I know Chrome 32-bit is old. I only used it to see if the error was JUST Firefox. I didn't know about Vivaldi. I will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/21290497/

Comment: BTW, I downloaded and installed Vivaldi 32-bit and uninstalled Google Chrome 32-bit. Still can't get to certain sites, though. It gives a message like Google Chrome did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your internet connection is being intercepted by a proxy server that acts as a man-in-the-middle even on connections that are supposed to be private and authentic. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu or applications running on your computer. The error message from your browser is meant to alert you that you're not actually talking to the server at `gog.com` but to someone else.

The certificate presented to your web browser declares that it has been issued by “Digital Reflection”. As far as I can tell they supply appliances to internet providers that allows the latter to collect data on their customers for marketing research which apparently includes the interception of supposedly secure connections.

You basically have two options here:

- Trust your internet provider and digital reflection to snoop on you “responsibly” without exposing you to security risks. In that case you can ask Firefox to trust their certificate authority for *all secured connections*. It's possible to apply this trust system-wide.
- Don't trust them and ask them to stop snooping on you or find a way around their connection interception with a VPN or equivalent.

If you need help with either of the two, please [ask a new question](/questions/ask) because it would lead to far away from the original question.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. I will have to look at what I think I need to do. Digital Reflections is a company I contracted with to monitor my web usage (like Neilson ratings but for the web). I think they only really work for Windows and Mac. I have tried to tell Firefox to ignore the warning but that doesn't work. I'll start a new question to see what option I can try.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16 it may be related to the network. Edit the  wireless connection, click on security, choose the "Use 802.1x ..." checkbox. Then choose the authentication method (typically FAST) and then under "Inner authentication:" enter the username and password you may need for the network.